# NHibernate DuplicateMappingException when two classes have the same name but different namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class in my domain model root that looks like this:

```
namespace Domain
{
  public class Foo { ... }
}
```

I also have another class with the same name in a different namespace:

```
namespace Domain.SubDomain
{
  public class Foo { ... }
}
```

For my mappings, I have a `Mapping` directory with a subdirectory called `SubDomain` that contains mappings for the domain classes found in `Domain.SubDomain` namespace.  They are all in the same assembly.

However, when I try to load them with NHibernate, I keep getting a `DuplicateMappingException`... even though both Foos having different namespaces.  The code I am using to load my NHibernate configuration is this:

```
var cfg = new Configuration()
  .Configure()                
  .AddAssembly("Domain");
```

How can I tell NHibernate to let me use two entities with the same name (but different namespaces)?

Comment: In case it helps anyone: same question for Fluent.nHibernate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290466/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090616013415/http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-mapping) on the Hibernate website:

> If you have two persistent classes
> with the same unqualified name, you
> should set `auto-import="false"`. An
> exception will result if you attempt
> to assign two classes to the same
> "imported" name.

I used that as an attribute for the `<hibernate-mapping>` tag and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

I have had the same problem. I solved it like this:

```
Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(...)
                .AdoNetBatchSize(500))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .Conventions.Setup(x => x.Add(AutoImport.Never()))
                .AddFromAssembly(...)
                .AddFromAssembly(...)
                .AddFromAssembly(...)
                .AddFromAssembly(...))
            ;
```

The imported part is: `.Conventions.Setup(x =>  x.Add(AutoImport.Never()))`.
Everything seems to be working fine with this configuration.

Comment: Could you please add an explanation of the table names used with this setup. Thanks.

Comment: Table names? By default, the class names are my table names. However, that can be specified individually.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a classes fully qualified name in the mapping document like so:

```
<class name="SeeMe.Data.People.Relationship, SeeMe.Data" ... > ...
```

Where SeeMe.Data is the assembly.

Comment: Still says: `NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException: duplicate import: Foo refers to both Domain.SubDomain.Foo, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null and Domain.Foo, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (try using auto-import="false")`

Comment: Dammit, soon as I copied and pasted that I saw the `auto-import="false"` suggestion... and it worked.

Comment: hehe saight, nHibernate rocks but I feel like it's not very intuitive. I've spent a lot of time banging my head over some silly mapping issue.