# Fluent NHibernate: What is AutoImport?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

What does the **AutoImport** convention in Fluen NHibernate do (with options Always or Never)?

I am having a really hard time with the documentation for Fluent NHibernate.  For example, there seem to a whole bunch of Convention Shortcuts, as described on the [conventions help page](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions).  However, I can not find a list of all of them, with their descriptions.

How does everyone else know which to use?  Surely they are not all reading through the source to work it out?! Is there a NHibernate web page I should be looking at?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the AutoImport is set to Never it makes you declare classes by using there whole name with namespace and if set to always you dont need the namespace. Its mentioned in this link below more extensive.

[Fluent NHibernate DuplicateMappingException with AutoMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290466/fluent-nhibernate-duplicatemappingexception-with-automapping)