# Using Castle ActiveRecord, I get an NHibernate DuplicateMappingException when two classes have the same name but different namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, castle-activerecord

The same problem as [NHibernate DuplicateMappingException when two classes have the same name but different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156281/nhibernate-duplicatemappingexception-when-two-classes-have-the-same-name-but-dif).  However, I'm using Castle ActiveRecord so I don't see how I can apply the same solution, using auto-import=false.  I dug through the AR code with Reflector but I don't see how I can control the mapping attributes that get generated.

Anyone have a way around this?

Thanks,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is boolean flag UseAutoImport passed to constructor of ActiveRecordAttribute. See link http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/attributedocs/Generated_ActiveRecordAttribute.html

Vij